# Using wget with both -O/--output-document and --backups options (doesn't seem to work)

Tags: shell, wget, gnu

I want to use wget with both the -O/--output-document option (save output to specified file name) and the --backups option (to rotate between given number of backups).

Simple test case:

`wget http://google.com -O myfile --backups=7`

Have to run at least twice to test backup behavior.
Expected behavior: After running twice, I would have both `myfile.1` and `myfile` in the output dir, with different timestamps.

Actual behavior: It just overwrites `myfile`, `myfile.1` is not created.

According to the documentation for the --backups option:
 (https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html),

> ‘--backups=backups’
>
> > Before (over)writing a file, back up an existing file by adding a ‘.1’ suffix (‘_1’ on VMS) to the file name. Such backup files are rotated to ‘.2’, ‘.3’, and so on, up to backups (and lost beyond that).

it should not overwrite without backing up the existing file first.  No mention is made in either this option or the -O/--output-document option that they shouldn't work together.

Is this correct?  Am I missing something?  Is this a bug?

I can see that under the `-O/--output-document` section it reads:

> Use of ‘-O’ is not intended to mean simply “use the name file instead of the one in the URL;” rather, it is analogous to shell redirection: ‘wget -O file http://foo’ is intended to work like ‘wget -O - http://foo > file’; file will be truncated immediately, and all downloaded content will be written there.

Still, I don't take that to mean that `--backups` shouldn't work, because it would still be a useful feature, even when concatenating all output to a single file.

Is there another way to do this? (I guess I could write my own backup rotation script, but that's a pain -- looking for something already pre-made if possible.)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I've been using is to just not use `-O`; instead I just let it save the output to whatever ends up being the default file name (often `index.html@param=value`, etc), and then copying that file to the desired destination *after* wget downloads it (and does its backup rotation).

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The --restrict-file-names=windows parameter makes the file names wget saves to
# more predictable and the same on both unix-like & windows hosts, so that our
# scripts will work both places. In windows filename mode, '?' in filenames are
# converted to '@'.
wget --backups=7 http://example.com/?param=xyz123 --restrict-file-names=windows

# Manually copy files to expected names after download so --backups option will work.
# (--backups option doesn't work in combination with -O/--output-file as of wget 1.19.1)
dest_filename="myfile.zip"
cp -a "index.html@param=xyz123" ${dest_filename}
```

In my experience, the invocation of wget like above ended up in filenames like `index.html@param=xxx` ... your mileage may vary; it's easy to check what the destination filename will be by just running wget and looking at the generated output file name.

Fancier applications which result in output filenames less easy to predict could probably be handled using filename globs or search commands, etc.

Comment: `--output-document` means "overwrite the file". If you do not want to overwrite the file you should not use `--output-document`. It is as easy as it sounds ;) But finally you should think about combining `--backups` with `--timestamping` so it does not re-download the file if it isn't newer.